# URL Redirect in PHP

Tags: php, url, redirect

I have 2 PHP Files in my project. index.php (My Form) and fillup-view.php (View)
My project is saved in localhost/exercise3 .

I have this on nav bar.

```
<li class="active"><a href="exercise3/index.php"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Forms</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="exercise3/fillup-view.php"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> View Forms</a></li>
```

but whenever I try to click the button, example the index.php .It should be directing in exercise3/index.php but it directs to /local-host/exercise3/exercise3/index.php . it adds another /excercise3 so I decided to to change it to

```
<li class="active"><a href="/index.php"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Forms</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="/fillup-view.php"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> View Forms</a></li>
```

but another problem again. /fillup-view is directed to local-host/fillup-view.php the exercise3 folder is not included. and when I tried to click the link for index.php it directs to localhost/xampp

can you help me out? thanks

Note. I just edit it to local-host because stackoverflow doesn't accept (localhost)

Comment: I think you should look up relative and absolute paths

Comment: like localhost/exercise3/index.php ?

Comment: Or use a BASE_URL in your configuration file to use across the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your first attempt, you did not add a `/` in front, so the path is relative to the current file. At your second attempt, you added a `/` in front, so it uses an absolute path (goes to the root of the domain). You could use either of the following:

```
<li class="active"><a href="/exercise3/index.php"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Forms</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="/exercise3/fillup-view.php"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> View Forms</a></li>
```

Or

```
<li class="active"><a href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Forms</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="fillup-view.php"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> View Forms</a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks! All your suggestion works. But this one has further explanation so I give it the plus :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
<li class="active"><a href="/exercise3/index.php"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Forms</a></li>
```

[View Forms](/exercise3/fillup-view.php)

Comment: Or like this `<a href="index.php">`

Answer (score 0):

do it like below

```
<li class="active"><a href="./index.php"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Forms</a></li>
```

View Forms